# What's the formula for the fixed point of a power tower of $2$s modulo $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

e.g., $n = 3$. Clearly, the powers of $2$ modulo $3$ alternate $2, 1$. The powers of $4$ modulo $3$ are all $1$s. So a power tower of $2$s modulo $3$ must get stuck on $1$. Of course this method is inefficient, as $n = 5$ already shows. Is there a formula, or at least a more efficient method?

p.s. I tried Mathematica's `FixedPoint` function but got very confused on the syntax, like whether to do `2, #` or `#, 2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking about this as a fixed point is a bit misleading, since $k \mapsto 2^k$ is not a well defined function from $\mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z}/n$. However, you are right that the sequence $2$, $2^2$, $2^{2^2}$, ... is eventually constant modulo $n$ for any $n$.

**Proof by induction on $n$:** Let $n = 2^k s$ for $s$ odd. By the Chinese remainder theorem, it is enough to prove that the sequence is eventually constant modulo $2^k$ and modulo $s$. The claim modulo $2^k$ is obvious -- the sequence is eventually zero. For $s$ odd, since $GCD(2,s) =1$, the value of $2^x$ modulo $s$ is determined by $x$ modulo $\phi(s)$. By induction, the sequence is eventually constant modulo $\phi(s)$, so it is also eventually constant modulo $s$ and we are done. $\square$.

Here is a straightforward Mathematica implementation.

```
oddPart[x_] := If[OddQ[x], x, oddPart[x/2]];
powerOfTwo[x_] := If[OddQ[x], 1, 2*powerOfTwo[x/2]];
eventualValue[1] = 0;
eventualValue[n_] :=
   With[{s = oddPart[n], t = powerOfTwo[n]},
     ChineseRemainder[{PowerMod[2, eventualValue[EulerPhi[s]], s] , 0}, {s, t}]];
```

The command `PowerMod[a,b,m]` computes $a^b \bmod m$ in a way which is faster and more memory efficient than `Mod[a^b,m]`. Other potential optimizations which I haven't implemented would be to [memoize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean) `eventualValue`, and to use bit shifting tricks to compute `oddPart` and `powerOfTwo`.

Answer (score -1):

If $n$ is even, then there is no such value. For $n$ odd, you can use [Carmichael's Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) (wich would be equivalent to Euler's Totient for an odd $n$)

Comment: The values of $2^{2^{2^{\cdots}}}$ stabilize modulo $n$ for any $n$, whether or not $n$ is even.